# How to eliminate this predefined macro in visual code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I write a `str` value in `python` in `VS Code` I have to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to avoid writing `%%!`. I want to just press enter to go to the next line, but I can't because it.

[image: It shows automaticly]

My question is, how can I eliminate it?